# Excel SUM From Different Sheets IF Date Found

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a workbook with separate sheets for each product (about 20 sheets, adding more on a regular basis). Each product is only available for a certain time frame, and has daily sales data recorded on that product's sheet. I want an overall snapshot across all products from any given date to be consolidated on a new sheet. This would sum from a particular column on each of the other sheets if a corresponding date exists.

I have a moderately passable function right now that has a separate VLOOKUP for each product sheet like `SUM(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(DATECELL,SHEETNAME!ARRAY,COLUMN... next VLOOKUP, next VLOOKUP etc.`, but it's incredibly cumbersome to update each function when a new product is added. I'm thinking there's a much easier way utilizing a named group (sheet names), SUMIF, VLOOKUP etc. Then when a new product sheet is added, I can simply add the sheet name to the named group rather than editing all the functions.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into the SUMIF and SUMIFS fuctions?

Comment: I have, it's combining it with vlookup (since the location of the particular date and therefore the data that needs pulling will be different on each sheet--or may not even exist) and the named group that I'm not sure of.

Comment: OK, to help make sure you get the best answer can you detail exactly why you can't have all the data in one table?

Comment: Thanks for your assist, btw.  The data is daily sales data for each product, which includes advertising cost, items, profit, etc for each day.  Recording all of this data for all of the products for every date on one table would be much less user friendly and less organized, especially when several new products are added each week, and may only last for a week.

Comment: No problem, btw :)  Having it on one table would be a question of making a raw data table, and then using Pivot Tables for agregated views and user friendly data presentation. Do you store and report on expired products?

Comment: Yeah, historical data for past products is super important, otherwise I'd just rotate out the data on the same sheet names and we'd be good.  As it is, new sheets are added for each product.  I wouldn't be opposed to a raw data table except that it would be difficult to update every day since the number of products offered will differ on any given day.  As it is the sheet template I'm using autopopulates the dates when I give the start and end parameters and it's relatively painless to just record units and advertising, which all other fields calculate from.

Comment: Essentially what I'm looking for is a way to sum a large number of these: =(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B10,2,FALSE)) each with different sheet names, and to add new sheet names easily.  Can this be done by referencing a list of sheet names?

Comment: Have you tried the Data->Consolidate function?  This will allow you to pick several ranges, and automatically sum up common (numeric) fields.

Comment: So, as a general rule, if the excel formulas are too cumbersome, you are heading for a vba-script (macro).  Don't get me wrong, someone might have a novel solution to simplify this, but, in my experience, you need to start looking at how you want to script it.  There is a lot more flexibility.  There are a lot of pluses to it too.  You could easily make the script (macro) so it will run on `Workbook_Change()` and this will make it so that you never have to modify the formula.  If you post your data (or a link), confirm that it will always be in the same format and we might be able to help.

Comment: Honestly it's a classic error, I once spoke with a man who had a spreadsheet on staff attendance. He had a seperate table, in a seperate sheet, for every month of the year... and was on to his third year! If the data is about the same thing, it belongs in the same table. My ideal model is one table for each *kind* of data, pivot tables and charts for display (and get PowerPivot to work with data from different tables in one pivot table!)

Comment: I respect the "all in one table"-suggestion, I do.  There are two reasons that impede the effecitivness of this solution: Does the OP have the power to make the decision to combine the table (not everyone owns the data provided to them), and if so, does the cost benefit of the decision to leave it separate versus combined make sense.  The OP's comments lead me to believe that he may be in a similar boat if he combines the data; he'll have to maintain the combined data in a fashion similar to the way he is now.  I guess we wait for @user329005 to provide feedback...

Answer (score 3):

You are on a road to misery with the multiple sheets design. I would consolidate onto one table (Insert ribbon, Table), then use the filter buttons in the first row for quick searching, add Pivot Tables and Charts for reports etc.

If you continue with separate sheet approach, expect to waste endless hours on this issue and the next issue and the next one.  As you yourself noted its "incredibly cumbersome".

Comment: +1, multiple sheets with the same data is never a good idea